# Can't get reset button to clear innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code so far added the reset button and a function for it. I want it to clear the textbox and the innerHTML but leave the original Enter any word.

```js
    function palindrome(){
        revString = "";
        inpString = document.getElementById("text").value;
        i = inpString.length;

        for(var j=i; j>=0; j--){
            revString = revString + inpString.charAt(j);
        }
        if(inpString === revString) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = inpString+" is a palindrome";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = inpString+" is not a palindrome";
        }
    }

    function clear()
    {   
        document.getElementById("reset").reset();
    }
```

```html
    <h1>Enter any word:<h1>
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="palindrome()">
    <button type="reset" id="reset">Clear</button>
    <p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: where is the script tag ?

Comment: When are your triggering clear()?

Comment: I think button should call the Clear() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reset button to work, it must be inside the same form as the elements to be cleared. Also have it run the function clearAnswer() (you can't call it clear) which clears the innerHtml of the response.

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = '';
```

```js
function palindrome(){
        revString = "";
        inpString = document.getElementById("text").value;
        i = inpString.length;

        for(var j=i; j>=0; j--){
            revString = revString + inpString.charAt(j);
        }
        if(inpString === revString) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = inpString+" is a palindrome";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = inpString+" is not a palindrome";
        }
    }

    function clearAnswer()
    {   
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = '';
    }
```

```html
    
    <h1>Enter any word:<h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="palindrome()">
      <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="clearAnswer()">Clear</button>
    </form>
    <p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: @PDKnight I don't know that there isn't CSS that uses the ID, or other functions that are attached. Onclick triggers the function; I could use form on reset, but why would I?

Comment: My bad, you're true :)